# coupled system of non-linear first-order ODEs

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have been posed the following question:
[image]

I'm not exactly sure if my approach is the correct one but here is my attempt so far:

$y_1 = h$ and $y_2 = h'$ and $y_3 = h''$

$y_4 = g$ and $y_5 = g'$

then rearranging $(1)$ and $(2)$ from the question:

- $y_1' = h'=y_2$
- $y_2' = h'' = \frac{2g^2 - (1/2)(y_1')- y_3'}{y_1}$
- $y_3' = h''' = 2g^2 - (1/2)(y_1')-(y_3)(y_1)$

and

- $y_4' = g' = \frac{y_5'+ y_4(h')}{h}$
- $y_5' = g'' = y_5(h)-y_4(h)$

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don’t remember a definition of a coupled system from my ODE course (I studied it more then twenty years ago  and in Russian). I tried to find this definition, but I failed. So maybe it means just a usual system if equations. Then we can proceed as follows.

> $y_1 = h$ and $y_2 = h'$ and $y_3 = h''$

$y_4 = g$ and $y_5 = g'$

Recall, that the right hand side of the new system has not contain derivatives. Thus

$$\cases{ 
y_1’=y_2\\
y_2’=y_3\\
y_3’=y_1y_3-\tfrac 12 y_2^2+2y_4^2\\
y_4’=y_5\\
y_5’=y_1y_5-y_2y_4}.
$$