# Writing coupled system of non-linear ODE's as a coupled system of nonlinear first order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Below I am given a coupled system of nonlinear ODEs:

[image]

I first considered equation $(1)$, and I defined some new functions.

$x_1 = h \implies x_1' = h' = x_2$

$x_2 = h' \implies x_2' = h'' = x_3$

$x_3 = h'' \implies x_3' = h''' = h''h + 0.5(h')^2 + 2g^2$

And likewise for equation (2), I defined some new function, $y_1$ to $y_2$, to get:

$y_2' = y_2h - y_1h'$

I was asked in the question to write $(1)$ and $(2)$ as a coupled system of nonlinear first-order ode's of the form:

$y' = f(y)$

I was hoping to know if I am on the right track so far? 
I am also thrown off by the part of the question where it asks me to write the coupled system in the form $y'=f(y)$.

Am I supposed to end up with one equation in the end, relation $h$ and $g$ ?

Thank you for your time

Comment: You are on the right track.  $f$ is a vector function, with one component for each of the variables you've introduced.

Comment: Does the answer in the previous version of this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3220642/115115, answer also your question?